# MySQL index sign of decimal

Tags: mysql

Is there an efficient way to index the sign of a DECIMAL column with MySQL (InnoDB)?

I've a query with the condition `where amount > 0` (and visa versa) and I'm wondering if there's a fancy way to make it speedy. In the same way that indexing the first character of a string can speed up a query like `select distinct left(some_string_column, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing the Decimal column will help MySQL to return result where `column > 0`.

```
  CREATE INDEX signindex ON table(deccolumn);
```

Besides, in order to allow MySQL to use indexes effectively, and avoid the use of a function in `where`, you can add a new column that has the pre-calculated data, and index that new column

```
 ALTER TABLE table ADD leftchar char(1);
 UPDATE table SET leftchar=left(some_string_column, 1);
 CREATE INDEX charindex ON table(leftchar);
 SELECT DISTINCT leftchar FROM table;
```